# Bundle load error when invoking bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to set up a ruby project and rather new to the process of automating via bundle. However when I try to execute any bundle command I'm met with the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle:26:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
      from /usr/local/bin/bundle:26:in `<main>'
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling Ruby, as well as removing the bundler gem itself. But to no avail. My Rubygems version is 2.3.0 and the Ruby version is 2.3.1 which is the latest stable version for Ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

Problem related to `bundler==1.16.1` try to reinstall with `bundler=1.16.0` for now.

```
gem uninstall bundler -x
gem install bundler -v 1.16.0 --force
```

More info and bug report can be found here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6227

Answer (score 0):

I was able to uninstall `bundler -v '1.16.1'` as described by Mr.Coffee, but in `gem list` it was still listed and marked as default.

I created a symlink then - very hacky, but the only thing which worked for me:

`ln -sf /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1`

The gem requesting `bundler` works now.